# tSQLt will not apply misnamed constraints (PK_dbo ....) to fake table

Tags: t-sql, tsqlt

Adding tSQLt tests to an existing production product, so we're not able to alter tables, constraints, etc.   Currently all the constraints are labeled like 'PK_dbo.ViolationCategory' when they should be like 'PK_ViolationCategory'

When I run:

```
    EXEC tSQLt.NewTestClass 'AdHocReportFiltersTestConstraint';
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE [AdHocReportFiltersTestConstraint].[Setup]
    AS
    BEGIN
        EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable 'dbo.AdHocReports'
    END
    GO


    CREATE PROCEDURE [AdHocReportFiltersTestConstraint].[test_AdHocReportFilters_Constraint]
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Id uniqueidentifier = NEWID()  
        DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(Max) = 'Test_Name'
        DECLARE @Value NVARCHAR(Max) = 'Test_Value'
        DECLARE @AdHocReport_ID uniqueidentifier = NEWID()  

        INSERT INTO dbo.AdHocReportFilters ([Id], [Name], [Value], [AdHocReport_Id])
            VALUES (@Id, @Name, @Value, @AdHocReport_ID)

            exec tSQLt.ApplyConstraint 'dbo.AdHocReports', 'PK_dbo.AdHocReportFilters';

    END


    EXEC tSQLt.RunTestClass 'AdHocReportFiltersTestConstraint';
    GO
```

I receive the error,

```
(1 row affected)
[AdHocReportFiltersTestConstraint].[test_AdHocReportFilters_Constraint] failed: 
(Error) The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint 
"FK_dbo.AdHocReportFilters_dbo.AdHocReports_AdHocReport_Id". The conflict occurred in 
database "CR", table "dbo.tSQLt_tempobject_fbc9c8bf09e742929eccae914d5e440d", 
column 'Id'.[16,0]{test_AdHocReportFilters_Constraint,11}
```

Any ideas of how to work around this?

Once I get this working, I will add a second record to violate the PK constraint and catch the error.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry.  Added clarification. ... Once I get this working, I will add a second record to violate the PK constraint and catch the erro

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at your code, I see you are doing the following:

1. Fake the table dbo.**AdHocReports**
2. Insert a row into the table dbo.**AdHocReportFilters**
3. Apply a PK constraint called "PK_dbo.AdHocReportFilters" to the table dbo.**AdHocReports**
4. You will then try and add another row to validate the PK_dbo.AdHocReportFilters constraint

The error you are getting appears to to suggest that you are violating a foreign key on the **AdHocReportFilters** table - which is expected since that table hasn't been faked.

It is not clear from the test name whether you are trying to validate the behaviour of the primary key or foreign key.

Looking at the steps, I think you may be mixing up the two tables but without more detailed code (i.e. CREATE TABLE) statements, it is difficult for me to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

There are two tables:

```
dbo.AdHocReports (Id,... (more columns))
dbo.AdHocReportFilters ([Id], [Name], [Value], [AdHocReport_Id] )
```

**AdHocReportFilters.AdHocReport_Id is foriegn key for table dbo.AdHocReportFilters referencing dbo.AdHocReports.Id**

When you are inserting insert a row in table `AdHocReportFilters`, you **should make sure** `AdHocReportFilters.AdHocReport_Id` is an `id column` in table `dbo.AdHocReports`

But in your SP, `@AdHocReport_ID` is `NEWID()`, which is of course a unique value and hence not in table `dbo.AdHocReports.Id`

Work around,

**Disable foreign key contraint**

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.AdHocReportFilters NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_dbo.AdHocReportFilters_dbo.AdHocReports_AdHocReport_Id
```